# iOS app lag....could Images be the culprit?

Tags: ios, image, swift, uiimage, lag

I recently uploaded a game on the app store.  It's a basic number guessing game similar to mastermind.  Anyways, the code is just a lot of conditions and a few loops, nothing that should cause any lag.  On my phone (iPhone 5s) it works fine.  On my friend's phone (iPhone 4s), he experiences lag.  Here is an image of the game:

[image]

You will press 6, and the 6 will appear in the white box.  Then you will press 5, and it will appear in the box after the 6, and so on.  He says that the first press will be okay, then on the second number press, the button will seem to remain pressed, and about a 15 second delay will happen before that number appears in the white box.  The same will happen with the 3rd.  I'm not sure what could be causing this large delay.  The only idea I have is due to my images...

As displayed in my debug, the sizes of those little number keys are 40px x 40px when displayed.  However, being relatively new to coding when I first started this app, the actual sizes of the images in the project are 500px x 500 px and didn't bother to use assets or anything, just figured if I made them large they'd scale down and be fine.  The Guess and Clear buttons are relatively larger as well.  So my question is...

Could this large difference in the scale between the image in the project and the actual size displayed on screen cause the lag?  I'm not sure because the images are all loaded up before the game is played, so why would it affect the game once those are all displayed?  And the fact that it doesn't lag on the first number push doesn't make sense (at least to me).  Also 15 seconds seems very long for just some image display lag.

Any input would be great thanks.

Comment: Why guess? Hook your friend's iPhone up to the [Xcode Time Profiler Instrument](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AnalysisTools/Reference/Instruments_User_Reference/TimeProfilerInstrument/TimeProfilerInstrument.html) and find out.

Comment: (But yes, scaling images is expensive, and iPhone 4s has a much slower CPU/GPU and half the RAM of your iPhone 5s.)

Comment: My friend is halfway across the country as of now, but I will have an iPhone 4s available to me in a few days.

Answer (score 1):

As Aaron suggests, measurement is much better than guesswork. Get a 4s, hook it up to instruments, and figure out what's *really* going on.

That being said, using large images and letting the system scale them is a very bad idea. It both uses gobs of memory *and* requires a lot of CPU time.

You should scale your images to the native display size(s) you need. We no longer need non-retina images for anything but the iPad 2/original iPad mini.

Asset catalogs make managing all those images much, much easier. Measure the display size on your screen, which will be in points, then create images that are 2x that size and save them into the @2x slot in an asset catalog. You should find that makes a big difference in performance.

Comment: The furthest I did with measuring was clicking the memory portion in xCode and watching what happened in the simulator.  However, I don't know if the simulator is reliable since it is just running off my computer and not the ACTUAL device.  But there were no memory spikes when I was clicking those particular buttons.  Not sure if that indicates that's not the problem, or if it just doesn't tell me anything because of what I mentioned above...

Comment: The simulator is just about useless for evaluating performance or memory usage. It is a fairly thin layer on top of Mac OS and actually runs against Mac OS frameworks. Further, it runs x86 code, not ARM code. You need to test on an iOS device.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm diving into the image assets right now and this is pretty easy to use stuff, especially having the ability to switch between iPad and iPhone.  Not wanting to create another entire question, do you know if using these image assets and specifying device is compatible with iOS 7.1 and up?  I'm assuming it is, but it would be nice to know for sure.

Comment: I believe asset catalogs are supported in iOS 7.0 and later, but that Xcode is actually smart enough to generate "flat" image files if your deployment target is an earlier OS version. (Which doesn't really matter these days since recent versions of Xcode don't support iOS <7 anyway.)

Comment: What do you mean that "recent versions of Xcode don't support iOS <7"? You can't write and deploy an app that runs on iOS 6 using Xcode 7?

Comment: You can deploy to them but can't make them the base SDK for development.

Comment: Seems that for my iPhone 4s and 5s, the size of the button is 40px, and for iPhone 6, it's 49 px.  Could I make it 50px to encompass all of those and make the @2x images using that 50, or will performance still suffer from scaling down 10 pixels for the 4s/5s?  I guess the other alternative is to check the size of the button when it scales and then do some if statements to pick one with an exact size, but not sure if that will make a difference...